# How can I get nullmailer to log more information?

Tags: logging, email

nullmailer logs when a message is sent out, but includes no information like the to-addresses, subject lines, which machine it's sending to, etc..

I can't find any documentation about how to change logging info.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

Looking into `nullmailer`'s source code, all the logging it implements is hardcoded stdout and stderr output without any conditionals. So there are probably no way without modifying its source.